# Apache POI Excel styles problem when creating two or more documents

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to create excel files with Apache POI and a template xlsx that gets filled with xml data.

My program in a nutshell:

1. reading excel template as a .xlsx file from my
   disk.
2. using the template i create a document using the data from a xml file that was given in as a parameter.
3. writing newly created excel to filesystem.

My problem is that i get errors when opening the created xlsx files:
[image: First error when trying to open the excel saying that excel found problems with the contents of this excel. Then Excel asks if they should restore as much of the excel as they can.]

If you click on yes you get a second window:
[image: This window says that excel "repaired" the formatting of the styles.xml part of the excel file]

After i clicked on close you can open the excel file with all the correct data inside but the formatting you did is gone (bold texts etc.).

**When does the error appear**

After some research i noticed that the first document that i create always comes out fine. Also in the tests i wrote all the tests run through normally as long as i only create one document at a time. The errors are only appearing when i try to create multiple documents in the same run without stopping java in between the documents. I can see this to an extent where i have three tests that all use the same input (both xml and excel template) and all run fine on their own but as soon as i start them together only the first one runs through normally and the two that are created afterwards are created with errors.

**The error**

While searching for the cause i've tried to find out what causes the error in the file in the first place so i've compared two excel files, both created with the same input data but one that opens just fine because it was created as the first document and one that shows the errors when opening:

[image]

**What i've tried to fix it**

1. I checked if it could be an error connected to the template but even if i use two seperate templates to create two documents, the second one gets produced with the error.
2. I checked if it helps when i trigger the java garbage collection manually but it did not change anything.
3. I checked if Apache POI has some kind of styles cache on any of their components that i have to clear but did not find any.
4. I tried to stop the java application after each document to work around the problem but that does not work for my case either, because the third party application that calls the java application cannot handle that.

**Maybe my styles are made badly?**

I've tried to optimise them but you tell me:

```
        //create styles
        //we will copy some settings off this cell later
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleTemplate = getCell(workbook, 0, "A6").getCellStyle();

        //standard cell style to copy
        XSSFCellStyle standardCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        standardCellStyle.setBorderBottom(cellStyleTemplate.getBorderTop()); //this is right - cell A6 has no bottom border, so we use the top border
        standardCellStyle.setBorderLeft(cellStyleTemplate.getBorderLeft());
        standardCellStyle.setBorderTop(cellStyleTemplate.getBorderTop());
        standardCellStyle.setBorderRight(cellStyleTemplate.getBorderRight());

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleBold = standardCellStyle.copy();
        cellStyleBold.setFont(getArial10Bold(workbook));
        cellStyleBold.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleBody = standardCellStyle.copy();

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleBodyDecimal = standardCellStyle.copy();
        cellStyleBodyDecimal.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleBodyRightAligned = standardCellStyle.copy();
        cellStyleBodyRightAligned.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleDate = standardCellStyle.copy();
        DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
        cellStyleDate.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("dd.mm.yy"));

        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleGesamttotal = standardCellStyle.copy();
        cellStyleGesamttotal.setFont(getArial10Bold(workbook));
        cellStyleGesamttotal.setFillForegroundColor(cellStyleTemplate.getFillForegroundXSSFColor()); //copy background color, they just call it foreground color
        cellStyleGesamttotal.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

before you ask: The styles are not created in any kind of loop but only once. ;)

**Additional Information**

How do i read in in the template:

```
    private static XSSFWorkbook readTemplate(String xlsxTemplatePath) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(xlsxTemplatePath);
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    }

    return myWorkBook;
}
```

How do i save multiple documents from this template:

Every time i call the method, i create one new document using the template using this helper method:

```
public static void saveWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook, String path) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After Workbook.write the Workbook cannot be used further. So the template must be opened again for the second and further result files. Is that done?

Yes every time i call the method i read in the template. So for every document that i create i read in the template separately.

Comment: I doubt help will be possible without having a complete example. At least we need to know how you are opening the template and how you are saving **multiple** result files from that template. After `Workbook.write` the `Workbook` cannot be used further. So the template must be opened again for the second and further result files. Is that done? Please do at least outline how.

Comment: Are you reusing your cell styles for multiple workbooks? CellStyles can't be reused between different workbooks. Something I've done to solve this, is to create a reusable `Template.xlsx` which already contains all the styles I need and then I just work with this workbook and save the finished version somewhere else.

Comment: hello @AxelRichter thank you for your questions. I've added the answers to the post. I hope this helps.

Comment: @magicmn thank you for the question. No i am not reusing the cell styles for multiple workbooks at least not to my knowledge. I create them newly for each of my documents. About the template.xlsx: I use a template but the styles that i need are for cells that are dynamic so i cannot add them to the template in advanche. Right?

Comment: Not reproducible having only the information in the question. I have put all your information into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) producing 3 result files from the template. Then I have run it. It works properly using `apache poi 5.1.0` and produces 3 proper result files.

Comment: @AxelRichter i was on version apache poi 4.1.2 initially but i just upgraded to 5.0.0 to test it (would have prefered 5.0.1 but my nexus does not have it yet) but i still get the same results. I will try to upgrade to 5.0.1 asap and try again.

Comment: It is not a versions problem. My minimal, reproducible example works using `apache poi 4.1.2` too. Files in `*.xlsx` format are `ZIP` archives. So you can unzip the result files and compare `/xl/styles.xml` of those result files. How differs that `XML` in proper files from that in not proper files?.

Comment: hello @AxelRichter 
Very good input! Thanks.
The only difference between the two style.xml files is one font that is present in the working version of the document but not in the one that cannot be opened properly.

        <font>
            <name val="Arial Bold" />
            <sz val="10.0" />
            <color indexed="8" />
            <b val="true" />
        </font>

Do you have any idea why this font would not be in certain files?

Comment: You say that font is in the template but not in some results created from that template? Then it would must have been deleted somehow. Nothing in your provided code can do this. So the problem is in code we do not know. Sorry, no help possible without [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

so i finally found the cause of the problem.

Big thank you to Axel Richter who showed me how to find the difference between the excel files with his comment that i can uncompress the excel files to compare the values.

The problem was this method:

```
  private static XSSFFont getArial10Bold(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    if (arial10Bold == null) {
      XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
      font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
      font.setFontName("Arial Bold");
      font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
      font.setBold(true);
      font.setItalic(false);
      arial10Bold = font;
    }
    return arial10Bold;
  }
```

or to be more precise the if-block around the creation of the font. It turns out that when i remove the if-block i no longer get the styles errors i've gotten before.

The problem was that while the font was written into a private class variable and reused afterwards, the important part that was missing was: `XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();` as this statement created the font inside the styles of the workbook and with that correctly added the font to the document. This part was only done once for the first document that was created. That is the reason why only the first document was created without style errors.

Comment: could you look into calling XSSFFont.registerTo(styleSheet) - the styleSheet can be retrieved from the XSSFWorkbook? This may return a different index which might be problematic.